# Python GUI (Tkinter) file browser and state the file selected on the blank

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, filebrowse

This GUI allows the user to open the file browser and select the files you need, show it on the field blank and then open the file once open is pressed. I'm new to python and had tried placing print tkFileDialog.askopenfilename() at the self.filename but this results in a syntax error. Please help. Thanks!

My question is as follows: 
1) Why does my file browser open twice upon pressing the "file browser" button.
2) Also, how do I state the directory of the file selected in the file blank instead of in the python command prompt?

I would like to open the file in the future after pressing the ok button.

```
from Tkinter import *
import csv
import tkFileDialog
class Window:       
 def __init__(self, master):     
    self.filename=""
    csvfile=Label(root, text="Load File:").grid(row=1, column=0)
    bar=Entry(master).grid(row=1, column=1) 

    #Buttons  
    y=12
    self.cbutton= Button(root, text="OK", command=self.process_csv) #command refer to process_csv
    y+=1
    self.cbutton.grid(row=15, column=3, sticky = W + E)
    self.bbutton= Button(root, text="File Browser", command=self.browsecsv) #open browser; refer to browsecsv
    self.bbutton.grid(row=1, column=3)

 def browsecsv(self):
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
    Tk().withdraw() 
    self.filename = askopenfilename()
    print tkFileDialog.askopenfilename() # print the file that you opened.

 def callback():
    abc = askopenfilename()
    execfile("input.xlsx")

 def process_csv(self):
    if self.filename:
        with open(self.filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
            logreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
            rownum=0

            for row in logreader:    
                NumColumns = len(row)        
                rownum += 1

            Matrix = [[0 for x in xrange(NumColumns)] for x in xrange(rownum)] 

root = Tk()
window=Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: for it opening twice- you are calling `askopenfilename` twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your both questions are connected. The problem is in your `browsecsv(self)` method. Your `directory` is already stored in `self.filename`, no need to call `askopenfilename()` again. That's the reason why the file browser opens twice. Moreover, to set text in your `Entry`, you need to assign it a text variable.

```
self.entryText = StringVar()
self.bar = Entry(root, textvariable=self.entryText ).grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Then, you can assign it to the `Entry` in your method:

```
def browsecsv(self):
   from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
   Tk().withdraw() 
   self.filename = askopenfilename()
   self.entryText.set(self.filename)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! By the way, may I ask how do I duplicate the load file and the entry blank row as I have a list of files that I would like to process after pressing file browser. I tried using loop at the def__init__ but kept getting errors. Thanks once again! @Matho

Comment: Sorry but I don't fully understand... You want to duplicate GUI objects (`Entry`, `Button` etc.) or their content (obtained `file` itself) ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I would like to duplicate the content (obtained file itself); such that I can select multiple files and processed them at one go. @Matho

Comment: Still not sure what do you mean, but I hope [this](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-copy-a-file-in-python-with-shutil/) might help. @Sandy